# Regex not able to identify emails with special characters?

Tags: regex, email

Problem:

I wrote a regex to identify email addresses in the text.But it is not recognizing the emails with special character like `-`.So I modified the regex to match emails with special characters.Now it is not matching normal email.s

```
regex = r"\"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@\w+\.\w+)\"?"
```

TEXT = "To address parsed is bilgi "

```
DETECT = "bilgi@kleintoys.com"
NOT_DETECT = "bilgi@klei-ntoys.com"
```

**Modified:**

```
regex = r"\"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@\w+\-+\w+\.\w+)\"?"
```

TEXT = "To address parsed is bilgi "

```
DETECT = "bilgi@klei-ntoys.com"
NOT_DETECT = "bilgi@kleintoys.com"
```

Is there any regex combining both these two regex to match both emails.
like

```
bilgi@klei-ntoys.com
bilgi@kleintoys.com
```

Comment: See [`\"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.\`?{}]+@\w+(?:-\w+)*\.\w+)\"?`](https://regex101.com/r/vWgIIK/1). You actually can enhance it further.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its not working in python.

Comment: It [works perfectly in Python](https://regex101.com/r/vWgIIK/2). Look, [a Python demo](https://ideone.com/CVvLud).

Comment: I'd like to suggest you [a lecture](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your pattern work, you need to add a part that will match 0+ sequences of `-` and then 1 or more word chars, `(?:-\w+)*`:

```
"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@\w+(?:-\w+)*\.\w+)"?
                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vWgIIK/2).

**Details**

- `"?` - an optional `"`
- `` ([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@\w+(?:-\w+)*.\w+) `` - Group 1 (what `re.findall` will output):

  - `` [-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+ `` - 1 or more chars defined in the character class (`-`, ASCII letters, digits, `.`, `` ` ``, `?`, `{`, `}` (note you might want to restrict this part to start with any letter and then also match `_`, like `` [^\W\d_][-\w.`?{}]* ``)
  - `@` - a `@`
  - `\w+`  - 1 or more letters/digits/`_`
  - `(?:-\w+)*` - 0+ sequences of `-` and then 1 or more letters/digits/`_`
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\w+` - 1 or more letters/digits/`_`
- `"?` - an optional `"`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/CVvLud):

```
import re
rx = r"\"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@\w+(?:-\w+)*\.\w+)\"?"
s = """ "bilgi@kleintoys.com"  and bilgi@klei-ntoys.com"""
print(re.findall(rx, s)) 
# => ['bilgi@kleintoys.com', 'bilgi@klei-ntoys.com']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make a much more loose regex.
Here is a proposition that does match both addresses:

```
[a-zA-Z\d]+@.+\..{,3}
```

Let's break it down:

```
[a-zA-Z\d]+@.+\.[a-zA-Z\d]{,3}

[a-zA-Z\d]                        Match any alphanumerical character...
          +                       ... at least once
           @                      Match the arobase
            .+                    Match any character at least once...
              \.                  ... before a dot
                [a-zA-Z\d]{,3}    Then check at least three alphanumerical characters
```

Checking with Python:

```
>>> import re    
>>> s = "bilgi@kle-intoys.com"    
>>> re.match("[a-zA-Z\d]+@.+\.[a-zA-Z\d]{,3}", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 20), match='bilgi@kle-intoys.com'>

>>> s = "bilgi@kleintoys.com"
>>> re.match("[a-zA-Z\d]+@.+\.[a-zA-Z\d]{,3}", s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 19), match='bilgi@kleintoys.com'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `*` instead of  `+`:

```
r"\"?([-a-zA-Z0-9.`?{}]+@\w+\-*\w+\.\w+)\"?"
```

A star after the hyphen matches zero or more occurrences. You have a plus which matches at least one hyphen. BTW, instead of `\-*` you may use `[-]*`. Between the square brackets any other special characters, besides `-`,  can be inserted.